# Error in getting a response from web service

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I created an Android app which must connect to a web service (created by me), which stores in a database (hosted in a site of free hosting). The web service takes `latitude`, `longitude` and `text` to store in the DB and it works great if I use it.

But I can't use the web service from my Android app.
Here is the code:

```
package com.example.mobile;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class WebServiceActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public final static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/InsertIntoDB";
    public final static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/Testing";
    public final static String NAMESPACE = "http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/";
    public final static String METHOD_NAME1 = "InsertIntoDB";
    public final static String METHOD_NAME2 = "Testing";
    public final static String URL = "http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/Service1.asmx?WSDL";

    Bundle extras;
    TextView tvResult;
    Button btnMenu;
    String ocr;
    int test_or_train; //valore sentinella
    String gps, latitude, longitude;
    double latitudine, longitudine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service);

        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        btnMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGoToMenu);

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ocr = extras.getString(RecognitionActivity.OCRTEXT);
        gps = extras.getString(RecognitionActivity.GPS);
        test_or_train = extras.getInt(RecognitionActivity.TEST_OR_TRAIN);

        String [] coordinate = gps.split("#");
        latitude = coordinate[0];
        longitude = coordinate[1];

        Log.d("VALORI", latitude);
        Log.d("VALORI", longitude);

        //latitudine = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        //longitudine = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

        System.out.println(latitudine);
        System.out.println(longitudine);

        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();

    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            perform();
            return null;
        }
    }

    void perform(){
        switch(test_or_train){
        case 0: //inserimento dei valori -- fase di training
            SoapObject requestInsert = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);//inizializzazione richiesta SOAP e aggiunta parametri

            //aggiunta dei parametri per la richiesta SOAP      
            requestInsert.addProperty("latitudine", latitude);
            requestInsert.addProperty("longitudine", longitude);
            requestInsert.addProperty("testo", ocr);

            //dichiarazione della versione SOAP utilizzata
            SoapSerializationEnvelope insertEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            insertEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestInsert);
            insertEnvelope.dotNet = true;


            try {
                HttpTransportSE insertTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                //chiamata del web service
                insertTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, insertEnvelope);

                SoapPrimitive insertResult = (SoapPrimitive)insertEnvelope.getResponse();

                if(insertResult != null)
                    tvResult.setText(insertResult.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;

        case 1:
            SoapObject requestTest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);

            requestTest.addProperty("latitudine", latitudine);
            requestTest.addProperty("longitudine", longitudine);
            requestTest.addProperty("testo", ocr);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope testEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            testEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestTest);
            testEnvelope.dotNet = true;

            try{
                HttpTransportSE testTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                testTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION2, testEnvelope);

                SoapObject testResult = (SoapObject)testEnvelope.bodyIn;

                if(testResult != null){
                      if((testResult.getProperty(0).toString()).compareTo("EXISTS") == 0)
                        tvResult.setText("Il cartello fotografato è presente nel DB");
                    else
                        tvResult.setText("Attenzione! Il cartello fotografato non è presente nel DB");
                    }

                }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;

            }
        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_web_service, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intentReset = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentReset);
    }
}
```

and this is the log cat that I get:

```
05-02 15:44:46.530: W/System.err(4670): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Po '')' at line 1' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41934a08
05-02 15:44:46.530: W/System.err(4670):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
05-02 15:44:46.530: W/System.err(4670):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
05-02 15:44:46.540: W/System.err(4670):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:116)
05-02 15:44:46.540: W/System.err(4670):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:259)
05-02 15:44:46.540: W/System.err(4670):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
```

Maybe there is a problem while I call the SOAP method, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try this SoapObjectresult = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;. Another issue to be taken care is you are updating ui in doInbackground(). Do it in onPostExecute()

Comment: it gives me a "RunTimeException" caused by a ClassCastException if I use SoapObject, that's why I use SoapPrimitive..

Comment: i think that the problem is here : 
  requestTest.addProperty("latitudine", latitudine);
  requestTest.addProperty("longitudine", longitudine);
  requestTest.addProperty("testo", ocr);
is that right to use addProperty this way to send 3 different values to the web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be calling the SOAP method correctly. The problem is on the web service itself.

Try this envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:ocr="http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ocr:InsertIntoDB>
         <ocr:latitudine>33</ocr:latitudine>
         <ocr:longitudine>44</ocr:longitudine>
         <ocr:testo>Po '</ocr:testo>
      </ocr:InsertIntoDB>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It will yeld the same error you pointed:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> You have an
         error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
         MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Po '')' at 
         line 1</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

On the other hand, when you take the `'` out:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:ocr="http://ocrwebservice.somee.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ocr:InsertIntoDB>
         <ocr:latitudine>33</ocr:latitudine>
         <ocr:longitudine>44</ocr:longitudine>
         <ocr:testo>Po </ocr:testo>
      </ocr:InsertIntoDB>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The insert is sucessful.

**Bottom line is:** either you client or your web service have to escape the `'` properly.

My opinion? This should be done in the web service and not in the client because unproper escaping leaves your service vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). Also `PO '` is not an invalid `String` per se and your service should not generate a fault for that.

Comment: with valid values (for example "Powe"), I get this error from the logcat: 
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4197e128

Comment: That is **not a problem of the web service**. Your business method who does insert (or select) on the database is not treating it's parameters correctly. Calling your business method with those parameters will yield an error. The web service is just forwarding that error.

Comment: In **the method who builds the SQL String that is sent to the database**. It is sending the wrong number of colums. For instance, the table, say `MYTABLE `, has 3 columns and it is sending something like `INSERT INTO MYTABLE ("value1", "value2")`. See? `MYTABLE` has **three** columns and it is only sending **two** values. Probably because one of the parameters sent to the method is `null`.

Comment: I tried to stamp on the logcat the values of **latitude, longitude and ocr**, which are the three values that I need to send, and they are not null. But I keep having this problem in contacting the web service..